# Timing issue C embedded

Tags: c, timer, embedded

I want to exit this while loop after 2 seconds if condition is not met. What value do I put in for timout here if the the clock frequency is 32MHz.

```
while(((READ_REG(ADC_NEW) & ADC_DATA) == 0) && (--timeout > 0));
```

Comment: No-one can answer this for you. How many instructions are in the loop? Who know's!?

Comment: Is it intended that  ADC_DATA == 0 as a criteria to stay in loop?.  If so, the statement should read `while(((READ_REG(ADC_NEW) && (ADC_DATA == 0) && (--timeout > 0));

Comment: No that is just a mask. That part is correct. I am just asking what value should timeout be for 2 seconds

Comment: First approach would be to use a disassembler to see what instruction set makes up your counter, then deriving a value.  Or, just use trial an error.  Start with a small value to see if loop exits at all, and work it up to a duration of 2 seconds.

Comment: You need to study some assembler and how C code is translated into machine code, because this question doesn't make any sense. Particularly, it doesn't make any sense unless a specific CPU is specified.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a timer-based solution?

Like

```
volatile bool adc_timeout_flag;

//configure timer for a desired frequency
config_timeout_tim();

//some code here

while(condition_for_adc_not_met() && (adc_timeout_flag == false));
adc_timeout_flag = false;
//something

void timerISR(void) {
  static uint32_t tim;
  ++tim;
  if (tim > TIM_MAX) {
    tim = 0;
    adc_timeout_flag = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any value you determine is likely to be different depending on:

- The processor architecture/instruction set.
- Whether the variable is located in on-chip memory, external memory, or a register.
- Different compiler options such as optimisation level.

Using simple loop-counters as timers is a poor choice in almost any circumstance - simply rebuilding your code with an upgraded compiler is likely to affect its timing.

Most microcontrollers have some sort of timing device; and you should use one of these to provide a deterministic timing source.  At its simplest, you would initialise the timer to increment a tick counter on an interrupt, and then poll that counter in your loop.

So given the pseudo-code:

```
static volatile unsigned sys_tick = 0 ;

__interrupt tickHandler()
{
    sys_tick++ ;
}

unsigned getTick()
{
    return sys_tick ;
}
```

Note this is pseudo-code - the real code will be hardware/compiler specific, and will require additional code if `unsigned` access is not atomic on your target.

Then your loop becomes:

```
unsigned start = getTick() ;
while( READ_REG(ADC_NEW) & ADC_DATA) == 0 && 
       (getTick() - start) < TICKS_PER_SECOND * 2 ) ;
```

If your target's standard library already implements `clock()` or you have retargetted it to your hardware then you already have the necessary timing support:

```
unsigned start = clock() ;
while( READ_REG(ADC_NEW) & ADC_DATA) == 0 && 
       (clock() - start) < CLOCKS_PER_SECOND * 2 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The basics of the answer are as follows:

```
time_outvalue = timeout_seconds / ( ( 1 / 32,000,000 ) * instructions_in_loop )
```

Assuming (and this assumption WILL be wrong!) there are three instructions (One for READ_REG, one for comparison, and one for the `timeout--` ) you get a value of around `21,333,333`

This is really not the way to do timeouts. Instead, have a periodic timer interrupt running and deal without time in there.

UPDATE: All bets are off with this solution if you have interrupts enabled.

Comment: Not if there are interrupts active. Then there is no practical ways to have exact timing by counting instructions. Even not if using ARM's DWT.

Comment: I don't think there's need for a downvote considering I said it WILL be wrong!

Comment: It's also reasonable to assume that someone who's reading ADC values in a loop is not using interrupts!

Comment: Why that? He could very well use a ready-made framework, e.g. RTOS which uses interrupts, or transfers data with interrupts. But I'm quite sure that he is not aware of them, taking the question into account.

Comment: @Olaf - Thank-you, I edited to include a note about this "solution" and interrupts.